# Most common tuples in Neo4j-DB

Tags: neo4j, cypher, combinatorics

I have nodes of orders and products in my database connected by a contains- relationship:

```
(:order)-[:contains]->(:product)
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to find the most common n-tuples of products that occur in the same order.

I'm afraid this is not possible as I have over 1500 products, making the number of possible combinations between these tremendously high even for small n ,e.g. 1500^4 ≈ 5*10^12.

I have written the following test query for n=3:

```
MATCH (o:order)-[r:contains]->(p:product)
WITH count(r) as NrProds, o 
MATCH (o)-[r:contains]->(p:product)
WHERE NrProds > 3
WITH o
MATCH  (o)-[r1:contains]->(p1:product),(o)-[r2:contains]->(p2:product),(o)-[r3:contains]->(p3:product)
WITH o,p1,p2,p3,count(r1) as r1,count(r2) as r2,count(r3) as r3
WITH  o,p1,p2,p3,
CASE WHEN r1<r2 AND r1<r3 THEN r1
     WHEN r2<r1 AND r2<r3 THEN r2
     WHEN r3<r1 AND r3<r2 THEN r3
     END as result
WITH result,o,p1,p2,p3
RETURN count(result) as NrPurchs, o.Id,p1.name,p2.name,p3.name ORDER BY NrPurchs DESC
```

First I make sure to not consider any orders of product count less than 3 as those make up a huge part of all orders, then I match over contains-relationships in these orders.
My computer does not finish the query which is not surprising given the large joins being created.

Is there a way of finding the tuples that does not involve querying over so many possibilites, such that my computer can finish the calculations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed out the number of combinations for product is too high so it is best to start generating the tuple from the order side to generate only existing tuples.

You have one unnecessary `MATCH` before your filter, following should be enough to filter out the orders with :

```
MATCH (o:order)-[r:contains]->(p:product)
WITH count(r) as NrProds, o 
WHERE NrProds >= 3 // note >= sign for orders with 3 and more
WITH o
...
```

or if your `order` uses `contains` relationship only for products:

```
MATCH (o:order)
WITH o,size((o)-[:contains]->()) as NrProds
WHERE NrProds >= 3
WITH o
...
```

To avoid duplicates filter out permutations of same products by sorting them by id, name etc.. (this where clause would only work for unique names/ids. If you have duplicates you need <= in there)

```
...
MATCH  (o)-[r1:contains]->(p1:product),(o)-[r2:contains]->(p2:product),(o)-[r3:contains]->(p3:product)
WHERE p1.name < p2.name AND p2.name < p3.name
...
```

then return each tuple with number of orders:

```
RETURN p1,p2,p3,COUNT(o) as c
```

(if you have multiple `contains` relationships between single order and product you should use `COUNT(DISTINCT o)`)

Finally return only N tuples:

```
ORDER BY c DESC LIMIT {n}
```

Whole query:

```
MATCH (o:order)
WITH o,size((o)-[:contains]->()) as NrProds
WHERE NrProds >= 3
WITH o
MATCH 
  (o)-[r1:contains]->(p1:product),
  (o)-[r2:contains]->(p2:product),
  (o)-[r3:contains]->(p3:product)
WHERE p1.name < p2.name AND p2.name < p3.name
RETURN p1,p2,p3,COUNT(o) as c
ORDER BY c DESC LIMIT {n}
```

Comment: This query is definitely much neater than mine. My computer even finishes if I wait long enough. So thanks for that.
Do you add the 
"WHERE p1.name < p2.name AND p2.name < p3.name"- line to keep orders from being enlisted 6=3! times rather than just once if the products p1,p2,p3 are contained in them?
How exactly does that work? By giving one option out of those 6 in which they may be arranged which is ok as we are not interested in the order but just the occurence?

Comment: Yes, the `WHERE` condition is there to avoid duplicates - I guess you consider p1,p2,p3 and p3,p2,p1, ... as identical. Try it with one order and products a,b,c and see what the second `MATCH` returns (without the aggregation after), what it returns when you use only half of the condition etc.. Understanding how cypher binds variables is important.